# Рефакторинг функций

Tags: инспекция-кода, f#

Нужно вытащить информацию с некоторого сайта. Для разбора HTML использую [F# Data: HTML Parser](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/HtmlParser.html) (`HTML Type Provider`, к сожалению, в данном случае неприменим).

Реализовал следующим образом:

```
let getNextLink (document : HtmlDocument) = 
    document.Descendants "a"
    |> Seq.choose
        (fun node ->
            match node.TryGetAttribute "href" with
            |Some href when node.InnerText().Trim() = "ключевое слово" -> 
               href.Value() |> Some
            |_ -> None)
    |> Seq.tryHead

let getAllValues start  = 
    let rec loop (pages : string) = seq {
        let result = HtmlDocument.Load pages
        yield 
            result.Descendants "div"
            |> Seq.filter
                (fun node -> 
                    match node.TryGetAttribute "id" with
                    |Some id -> id.Value().StartsWith("текст для проверки")
                    |None -> false)
            |> Seq.map
                (fun node -> node.InnerText())
        let next = getNextLink result
        if next.IsSome then
            yield! loop next.Value

    }
    loop start

let path = "http://адрес.html"

let values =
    getAllValues path
    |> Seq.concat
```

остальная часть связана с обработкой полученных данных и к текущему вопросу отношения не имеет.
Интересует как правильность выбора библиотеки для парсинга, так и сама реализация.

Comment: В чём конкретно вопрос? Вам нужно просто чтобы кто-то вычитал ваше решение и нашёл ошибки?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin да, просто ревью кода - сами функции рабочие

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, да, так можно, cr входит в тематику ru.so смотри метку "инспекция-кода"

Comment: Могу предложить только в функции `Seq.filter` использовать `Option.exists`

Comment: @FoggyFinder , Спасибо...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В целом функционально. Но если вы стремитесь к совершенству, то вот несколько советов:

1. Вся обработка происходит как бы вместе, в один присест. Весь код находится в одной большой функции с подфункциями, и это делает код гораздо менее читаемым и запутанным. Я обычно стараюсь разбить код на много мелких функций, и потом их друг с другом стыковать. Идея в том, что каждая функция должна читаться на одном уровне, а не на нескольких. Например "*для каждого А вычислить Б*", а не "*для каждого А, где А - это все X из Y, для которых выполняется Z, вычислить Б, где Б - это P или Q в зависимости от I + J*". Человечский мозг очень плохо справляется с частым переключением контекста.
2. Везде используются методы классов, что затрудняет вывод типов, заставляет указывать типы явно, заставляет использовать лямбда-выражения. Я обычно стараюсь оборачивать методы классов в мелкие функции, которые потом можно легко стыковать.
3. Очень мало параметризации, все строки зашиты в код. Если строки `"id"`, `"a"` и `"href"` ещё можно понять как часть стабильного стандарта, то строки `"ключевое слово"` и `"текст для проверки"` совершенно точно должны быть параметрами.
4. Основной цикл у вас выдаёт последовательность последовательностей - `seq<seq<string>>`, и потом вы её склеиваете с помощью `Seq.concat`. Эта операция видится мне лишней: раз уж вы используете выражение `seq { }`, то можно внутри него сразу разворачивать последовательности используя `yield!` вместо `yield`.
5. Здесь я не уверен, возможно это у вас такое требование, но: что происходит, если на странице есть несколько ссылок с текстом "ключевое слово"? Ваша функция `getNextLink` вернёт только первую ссылку, а остальные вы теряете. Можно было бы совсем без затрат устроить обработку всех ссылок, а не только первой, просто убрав `Seq.tryHead` из `getNextLink`. Но я не уверен, что это будет "лучше" в вашей ситуации.

Вот что у меня получилось в результате применения этих советов:

```
let attr name (node: HtmlNode) = node.TryGetAttribute name |> Option.map (fun v -> v.Value())
let text (node: HtmlNode) = node.InnerText()
let trim (s: string) = s.Trim()
let descendants tag (node: #HtmlNode) = node.Descendants tag
let startsWith prefix (s: string) = s.StartsWith prefix

let hasText value node = trim (text node) = value
let hasId value node = attr "id" |> Option.exists (startsWith value)

let getNextLink text = 
    descendants "a"
    >> Seq.filter (hasText text)
    >> Seq.choose (attr "href")
    >> Seq.tryHead

let linksOnPage idPrefix doc =
    descendants "div" 
    >> Seq.filter (hasId idPrefix)
    >> Seq.map text

let getAllValues linkText idPrefix start  = 
    let rec linksFromPageTree (url : string) = 
        seq {
            let doc = HtmlDocument.Load url
            yield! linksOnPage idPrefix doc
            yield! nextSubTree doc
        }
    and nextSubTree doc = 
        match getNextLink linkText doc with
        | None -> Seq.empty
        | Some nextUrl -> linksFromPageTree nextUrl

    linksFromPageTree start

let path = "http://адрес.html"
let values = getAllValues "ключевое слово" "текст для проверки" path
```

Comment: Возможно вам будет это интересно - в [F# Slack](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/) открылся канал для обсуждения F# на русском языке. Для того, чтобы туда попасть нужно только присоединиться к [F# Software Foundation](http://foundation.fsharp.org/join) и после этого вы должны получить приглашение в slack.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже там состою :-)

Comment: действительно =)

Comment: (надеюсь, вы не возражаете, что я добавил вас к каналу)

Comment: Не возражаю, спасибо.